# List of Python format characters

Tags: python, format, character

I've been looking for the list Python format characters for a good 30 minutes. I can't find any.

Examples are

> %d, %r

etc but I need a list with them along with a description if possible please.

Comment: Check out https://pyformat.info/

Comment: See [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for `.format` and string literal formatting options.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Here you go, Python documentation on [old string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). tutorial -> 7.1.1. Old String Formatting -> "More information can be found in the [link] section".

Note that you should start using the [new string formatting](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) when possible.

Comment: You should use new string formatting when *appropriate*; there are a great many cases where standard string formatting is much more appropriate.

Comment: The actual *list of format characters* can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) (under 'type').

Answer (score 7):

It's the first result on Google: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

See also the new format() function: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

Comment: It's the first result on Google *no matter what you search for?*  Need to give the search terms you used, so Freddie Rice has a chance to learn how to improve (as marcog did on a comment on the question).

Comment: Heh, yeah. My first hit brought me here.

Answer (score 6):

In docs.python.org Topic = 5.6.2. String Formatting Operations
    http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting
then further down to the chart 
    (text above chart is "The conversion types are:")

### The chart lists 16 types and some following notes.

My comment: help does not include attitude which is a bonus.
The attitude post enabled me to search further and find the info.

Comment: Link to the section in current docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting